# eg-01-java-jwt example returning empty body

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use the example project, but I keep getting this message:

```
DocuSign Exception!
    Reason: 0
    Error Reponse: null
```

I have configured everything following the instructions in the repository page.
I have tried debugging the class responsible for the HTTP Post, but so far I got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to grant consent for the integration key to impersonate the user.

See https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/issues/111#issuecomment-513537950

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Comment: Glad to hear! I've filed internal ticket DCM-3410 to enable the example to provide better diagnostics.